# How can i change the format of text using sed?

Tags: sed

```
cat > inputfile

X1 a1,b1,c1,d1.................. dn
X2 a2,b2,c2,d2.................. and so on upto n
................................................
................................................
Xn an,bn,cn,dn....................and so on upto n
```

output format:

```
X1 a1 +
   b1 +
   c1 +
   .
   .
   .
   .

X2 a2 +
   b2 +
   c2 +
   .
   .
   .


and so on
```

I am trying something like

```
 sed ':b;s/,/\
/;tb;s/\
/ +/g'
```

NOTE : I need to add a tab before `b1 +,c1 +....` ,`b2 +,c2 +,...` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this inputfile:

```
X1 a1,b1,c1,d1
X2 a2,b2,c2,d2
X3 a3,b3,c3,d3
X4 a4,b4,c4,d4
```

With sed (using bash [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) for clarity):

```
sed $'s/,/ +\\\n\t/g' inputfile
```

```
X1 a1 +
    b1 +
    c1 +
    d1
X2 a2 +
    b2 +
    c2 +
    d2
X3 a3 +
    b3 +
    c3 +
    d3
X4 a4 +
    b4 +
    c4 +
    d4
```

sed needs to see a backslash before the newline, otherwise you get an "unterminated s command" error